# Does drive.revisions.list supported for forms?

Tags: google-drive-api

We have a file which is a form which we can't call revisions.list on. Its hard for us to confirm fully, though looking at our app logs, we have indications that in the past this might have worked and started failing at ~5PM PST on 7/25/2013.

Is the revisions.list API supported for forms?

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Aq0B5MZWpxqydGdfQUVzSzFOQnNWYUtQUG9FMTRyNWc/revisions?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer [DELETED]
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer


400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "File does not support revisions"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "File does not support revisions"
 }
}
```

Comment: One of the recent changes broke revisions support for Forms. I'm looking into it to confirm our plans about supporting revisions for Forms files.

Comment: Any update on if this is breakage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by one of the recent changes we made. We fixed the issue, it's scheduled to be deployed with the next push.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. We have implemented a temporary workaround in our application to disable forms support to work around the issue so that our users don't see errors. 

Any chance you can update this thread when the fix goes live so we can revert our workaround ?

Comment: @burcu-dogan did You fix the issue? I meet same problem now